# Does for..in traverse property overwritten by non-enumerable property in prototype chain?

Tags: javascript

`for..in` traverses all enumerable `String` property according to [ES6](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-ordinary-object-internal-methods-and-internal-slots-enumerate), does it need to visit the same property is it is overwritten (same property string) by non-enumerable property in its decendant? Like in below code `Object.prototype.indexOf` is not traversed for `Array`. The pseduo code in above link only implies duplicated enumerable property is not enumerated again and seems doesn't cover this case.

```js
Object.prototype.indexOf = "test";
var arr = [];
for (var item in arr) {
  // Object.prototype.indexOf is overwritten for arr by Array.prototype.indexOf,
  // the latter is non-enumerable
  console.log(item);
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure why you think the pseudo code doesn't cover this case? It seems quite clear to me.

Comment: @Bergi you are right, I missed the recursion part of the pseudo code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`for...in` loops iterate the properties given by the [EnumerateObjectProperties](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/#sec-enumerate-object-properties) iterator.

> Enumerating the properties of the target object includes enumerating
>   properties of its prototype, and the prototype of the prototype, and
>   so on, recursively; but a property of a prototype is not processed if
>   it has the same name as a property that has already been processed by
>   the iterator's `next` method. The values of [[Enumerable]] attributes
>   are not considered when determining if a property of a prototype
>   object has already been processed.

So yes, if your object has a non-enumerable property, it will be processed but not iterated. If further in the prototype chain there is the same property but now enumerable, it will be considered processed and thus it won't be iterated.

You can see in the proposed implementation code that the key is always added to the visited set, even when not yielded because of non-enumerability.

```
function* EnumerateObjectProperties(obj) {
  let visited = new Set;
  for (let key of Reflect.ownKeys(obj)) {
    if (typeof key === "string") {
      let desc = Reflect.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(obj, key);
      if (desc && !visited.has(key)) {
        visited.add(key); // <-- Added even if not enumerable
        if (desc.enumerable) yield key;
      }
    }
  }
  let proto = Reflect.getPrototypeOf(obj)
  if (proto === null) return;
  for (let protoName of EnumerateObjectProperties(proto)) {
    if (!visited.has(protoName)) yield protoName;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

No, non-enumerable property names are not enumerated. Regardless whether they shadow enumerable inherited properties or not.

Both your test and the linked specification text confirm this:

> […] a property of a prototype is not processed if it has the same name as a property that has already been processed […]